# Unity 3D iOS / Android - How to execute statements if access to the device was denied?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

Good Day!

I'm not aware if my question was already answered. Anyway I would like to ask:
For example, when an app will access to the web cam or any other devices, it usually prompts for an access permission to device in which the user will choose if he/she allows it or not. I just want to create a condition statement in Unity3d C# if the access was denied or allowed a set of codes would be implemented.

It goes like this

```
if (webcam is allowed)
   execute this statements
else
   execute this statements.
```

Is it possible?
I'm hoping for a positive response.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a direct way to access this information - one would think `Application.HasUserAuthorization()` would work, but it apparently only works with the Web Player. Perhaps you can check the result of [`WebCamTexture.devices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-devices.html), maybe it'll be null/empty if permissions weren't given?

Comment: Sadly I think you will have to write plugins for this.I already found a iOS solution. Writing a java plugin for the android version would not be that hard too. Here is the iOS [solution](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/request-and-get-state-of-camera-permission.281858/)

Comment: @Serlite I'll try your suggestion, I'm just thinking... it make sense. Thanks in advance my friend.

Comment: @UriPopov Honestly I don't have experience developing native android apps although I have experience in Java but for console applications only. That would be a problem to me.